# Remix not found when deploying with render.com

Tags: node.js, deployment, remix, render.com

I have been working on a portfolio website that uses the Remix stack, but I can't deploy it as of right now. It runs perfectly fine in my terminal + localhost, but it shows that remix is not found when I deploy. What could be causing the issue? I should also note that I am using a SQLite database, so would there be any issues with that when deploying to render? Here are more details about the error:

```
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  ==> Using Node version 14.17.0 (default)
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  ==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  ==> Running build command 'npm run build'...
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  > my-remix-app@ build /opt/render/project/src
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  > remix build
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  sh: 1: remix: not found
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  npm ERR! syscall spawn
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  npm ERR! file sh
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  npm ERR! errno ENOENT
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  npm ERR! my-remix-app@ build: `remix build`
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  npm ERR!
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  npm ERR! Failed at the my-remix-app@ build script.
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  npm ERR!     /opt/render/.cache/_logs/2023-09-23T17_29_26_844Z-debug.log
Sep 23 01:29:26 PM  ==> Build failed
```

I tried a variety of things, includind reinstalling packages, remix cli, etc. I just can't pinpoint why it works on my end but not when deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I can see from the logs that you're using the default version render provides (`14.17.0`). You probably need to set it to the version you're using locally. https://render.com/docs/node-version has options you can use to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of things & solved it by using `remix-serve ./build/index.js` in `package.json` on a self-hosted VPS with easypanel, not render. But this seems like a Remix bug.

Make sure to clear cache & redeploy.